# How to resolve a require string within a custom webpack loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm writing a custom loader for webpack.

Within my loader I've got a require string like this:

```
"css!less!./myFile.less"
```

**Is there a way to get the output of the resolved request?**

I'm looking for the output of the module after all loaders have been applied. Or in other words:

**How do I get the compiled css from the string above?**

I tried to use `this.resolve` on the loader context:

```
this.resolve(this.context, "css!less!./myFile.less", function(err, result){
     // Best case scenario so far: 
     // result == "./myFile.less"

     // How do I get the css from myFile.less here? 
     // Is that even possible/the right way to get this?
});
```

But I can't seem to get the resolved output.
I'm probably doing something wrong, the only documentation I've found about this function is here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#resolve

Comment: Can you please describe the whole task? Why you need an external modules in your loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a (so far) undocumented method:

```
this.loadModule(request, callback:function(err, source));
```

This method will load the module and apply all loaders before calling the callback.